# Column range chart columns top alignment

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Column range chart with inverted=true, the height of the chart is fixed, but there are cases that only one column will show, how can I align this column to the top of the chart because the default is vertical align middle. Thank you very much!

Comment: Any example code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the chart to leave room for bars that are not present, you can set the x axis min/max accordingly.

(ie if you have 6 categories, and you want to always show 6 categories even if there are not 6 data points, set your x axis `min` to 0 and `max` to 5).

If you want the single data point to always be at the top, you will need to ensure that its x value is 0 - the first spot.

example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/f28txe9u/

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is what I was looking for! Is there a way to hide the auto generated numbers on x axis and only show the first category? Thanks

Comment: easiest way is probably to use tickPositions: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/f28txe9u/1/